Generalized Exponential Function series representation
I'm working on retrieving kinetics parameter from thermogravimetric data, and found THE paper on the subject, but upon reviewing the equation development they make a statement that got me totally bugged.
They say that the integral $\displaystyle \int_u^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-n}\mathrm{d}u \approx u^{1-n}e^{-u}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(b)_k}{u^{k+1}}$ and points to the Special Function book from Earl D. Rainville.
Upon reviewing the literature I've discovered that the integral above is related to the generalized exponential function ($E_n(x)$) and various are the series representations for it, but the one that I am most interested in is the $E_2(x)$ series representation, because after a substitution is applied to the integral
$$\displaystyle \int_0^T e^{-E/RT} \ \mathrm{d} T$$
we arrive at
$$\displaystyle \int_{E/RT}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u^2}\ \mathrm{d} u$$
wich in terms of $E_2(x)$ can be written as $\displaystyle \left(\frac{E}{RT}\right) E_2\left(\frac{E}{RT}\right)$.
The problem I am facing in the moment is that most likelly the author of the paper in question have used the approximation
$$E_n(z) \approx \Gamma(1-n)\left[ z^{n+1} - e^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(2-n+k)} \right]$$
that diverges for $n=2$ since $\Gamma(1-n)=(-n)!\to\infty$
Is there any other series representation for this function for $n\geq2$?
Links:
1 Article
2 Generalized exponential function

Don't use $u$ as both the limit and the variable

@user619894 I understand that this is not the correct way of writing an integral and it's limits, but inside fields like physics, chemistry and engineering this is very common. That said, for that particular equation I've just copied from the article as it was.

https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19 gives the series expansion of $E_n(x)$
